# Moved from iis6 to 7.5 asp.net session timeouts

Tags: asp.net, session

After moving over to the new platform the site is logging people out after a time of inactivity. This never used to happen and I wish to set the timeout to a larger value. I've changed some settings to no effect and even in code the session.timeout is set to 1440.

Any ideas where I can find another setting for it or where I might start with this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Are you setting your timeout in your global web.config?

Comment: Could you clarify the 'global' web.config. The web.config in the root of the website folder does not set the timeout. however it is set via code after login but this must be superceeded elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app pool was recycling as the worker process was set to expire after 20 minutes of inactivity.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at IIS session information here: [HttpSessionState.Timeout Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout.aspx)

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <sessionState 
      mode="InProc"
      cookieless="true"
      timeout="30" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: There is no such section in the websites config file.

Comment: @Robert you can add the section.

Comment: Ok I did add the section and it recycled as expected so all were 'logged out' however the problem is still occuring.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this section to your web.config in your website root dir for authentication:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms"> 
        <forms timeout="1440" slidingExpiration="true"/> 
    </authentication> 
</system.web>
```

Assuming that you're using Forms authentication.

And this for session timeout:

```
<system.web>  
    <sessionState timeout="1440"/>  
<system.web>
```

Comment: auth mode is windows. It's the intranet site. :)  I'm just clueless where to look next,  mostly as it was fine before the migration.

Comment: You can change the auth mode to mode="Windows", too

Comment: It is windows already and now session state timeout is set to 1440.  still kicking out users after a period of no use. :(

Comment: To test, I'd make sure you're setting it in the web.config and no where else, especially not setting it programatically.